# How can I back up a computer with PGP whole disk encryption enabled?

Tags: backup, encryption

My mac has PGP whole disk encryption (WDE) installed.  I would like to back up my entire drive.  However, the backup must also be encrypted (although not necessarily with PGP WDE).  I need to be able to completely restore the computer (system files, etc.) from this backup.

The only instructions I have found for backing up such a drive are for Windows: [HOW TO: Create Backup Images of Whole Disk Encrypted Drives or files](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO41997).

I am on Snow Leopard so an encrypted File Vault backup is not an option for me.  Is there any way to create a byte-for-byte image of my disk?

Answer (score 2):

See [this article](http://forum.pgp.com/t5/PGP-Desktop-for-Macintosh/Superduper-and-PGP-9-x-and-restoring-from-a-clone-Mac-OSX/td-p/24805) in the PGP forum. It recommends to enable WDE on the target and then use SuperDuper or Carbon Copy Cloner to transfer data (or restore from Time Machine).